# file sharing with password

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-share

I am trying to share a directory with password and connect to it from another computer.
i was trying to use NetUseAdd from win32net and the return value is None but when i try to open a file the error is:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

The code for connecting is:

```
use_dict={}
use_dict['remote'] = unicode('//servername/test')
use_dict['password']=unicode(password)
win32net.NetUseAdd(None, 2, use_dict)
file = open('//servername/test/file in the directory','rb')
```

and the code for sharing is:

```
dict={'netname': "test", 'type' : 0,'permissions' : 
                    1,'max_uses':-1,'path':directory, 'passwd': password } 

win32net.NetShareAdd(None,2,dict)
```

can u help me understand what the problem might be?

note: as written in the commments i ran both codes as admin

Comment: Maybe you have to execute it as admin?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say i ran it as admin

Comment: What happens when you try to access the file from a Windows console? For example `type "\\servername\test\file in the directory"`

Comment: i get : Access is denied